# How does clojure.core/compare implement java.util.Comparator?

Tags: clojure, type-hinting, clojure-java-interop

I saw this code in clojure.core recently.

```
(defn sort-by
  "Returns a sorted sequence of the items in coll, where the sort
  order is determined by comparing (keyfn item).  If no comparator is
  supplied, uses compare.  comparator must implement
  java.util.Comparator.  If coll is a Java array, it will be modified.
  To avoid this, sort a copy of the array."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([keyfn coll]
   (sort-by keyfn compare coll))
  ([keyfn ^java.util.Comparator comp coll]
   (sort (fn [x y] (. comp (compare (keyfn x) (keyfn y)))) coll)))
```

There is a `Comparator` type hint on the argument `comp`. But the two argument version of `sort-by` passes `clojure.core/compare` to it. How does this work?

Update:

I would like to know how `clojure.core/compare` implements `java.util.Comparator`. `compare` looks like this:

```
(defn compare
  "Comparator. Returns a negative number, zero, or a positive number
  when x is logically 'less than', 'equal to', or 'greater than'
  y. Same as Java x.compareTo(y) except it also works for nil, and
  compares numbers and collections in a type-independent manner. x
  must implement Comparable"
  {
   :inline (fn [x y] `(. clojure.lang.Util compare ~x ~y))
   :added "1.0"}
  [x y] (. clojure.lang.Util (compare x y)))
```

Isnt't this just a normal clojure function?

Comment: How does what work, exactly?  `compare` implements `java.util.Comparator`.  Are you asking (a) how it does so?  (b) how 2-ary and 3-ary definitions work? (c) How the type hint helps anything?  (d) how the `sort-by` function itself works in the 3-ary case?  (e) something else?

Comment: I extended my question. It's (a).

Comment: Adjusted the title to be on-point for the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `jvm/clojure/lang/AFunction.java`:

```java
public abstract class AFunction extends AFn implements IObj, Comparator, Fn, Serializable {

/* ...omitted... */

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
        Object o = invoke(o1, o2);

        if(o instanceof Boolean)
                {
                if(RT.booleanCast(o))
                        return -1;
                return RT.booleanCast(invoke(o2,o1))? 1 : 0;
                }

        Number n = (Number) o;
        return n.intValue();
}
}
```

When the Clojure compiler is compiling functions, it either implements them as derivatives of RestFn (if variadic) or AFunction (otherwise); however, RestFn extends AFunction, so it all ends up at the same place.

So: All Clojure functions implement Comparator through AFunction, either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Below is my answer based on *my confusion* on what was asked: I thought the question was about the 3-arity overload instead of the 2-arity overload.

---

I think the confusion comes from the phrase "the two argument version of sort-by passes `clojure.core/compare` to it". That's not right. Let's see the code:

```
(. comp (compare (keyfn x) (keyfn y)))
```

It's using the "dot special form" (see the `.` as first element of the list). It's being used here as a method call. It will call the method `compare` on the instance represented by `comp` with the args `(keyfn x) (keyfn y)`. `clojure.core/compare` has nothing to do here. From [the various forms of dot expressions](http://clojure.org/java_interop#toc7), this matches the following case:

```
(. instance-expr (method-symbol args*))
```

About the type hint: it's just a performance optimization to avoid reflection in that method call.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but when i call `(sort-by key-fn coll)` (the two argument version) then it delegates to `(sort-by key-fn compare coll)`. Is that `compare` which is passed to the 3-argument version also not the function defined in `clojure.core`?

Comment: What is being called is the compare method on the clojure.core/compare function in the 2-arity overload, so your statement that it does not has anything to do there is untrue. - @Finn your observation is correct I believe.

Comment: Yes, my fault, I misread the question and thought it was about the 3-arity overload. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Added an update to this answer.  The correct answer is the one from Charles Duffy. I'm keeping this because I'm not sure about the delete answer etiquette, and because I think it has useful information (for a different question though)

Comment: Since this answer arguably adds value to the site, I think you're right to not delete it: It's not factually incorrect; it's simply off-point -- but other people have found it interesting and upvoted.